# jndi look up for DefaultFtpSessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jndi, spring-integration

I have ftp connection properties in .properties file and following code for spring bean.

```
<bean id="ftpConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${ftp.host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${ftp.port}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${ftp.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${ftp.password}"/>
    </bean>
```

Above method does work using properties file inside web app and placeholder configuration. But what I want is to keep these properties in server, let's say tomcat context.xml file.

I have spring integration which uses this factory.

```
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound"
        channel="ftpChannel"
        remote-directory="${ftp.remoteDir}" 
        remote-file-separator="\"
        session-factory="ftpConnectionFactory"
         />
```

Is there a way that I can externalize these properties in server and look up using jndi. For datasource I am currently doing it. But I don't know how to do it for session factory. The reason why I want to do this is to hide the password and other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Tomcat can correctly bind the object to the JNDI from `context.xml`, there is no difference to get access to that object from JNDI lookup as you do it for `DataSource`.

Show, please, how you do it for `DataSource` from Spring, and how you configure `ftpConnectionFactory`, and I'll try to help you.

Comment: I have `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
     <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource"/>
 </bean>` in spring configuration with Resource in context file. I could do the same thing to this ftp session factory too right?

Comment: Exactly! There is no difference for JNDI which object you bound and want to get. If your Tomcat does it for you, so you can use `JndiObjectFactoryBean` to get desired object from JNDI

Answer (score 1):

You could use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer as follows

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
          <value>classpath:external.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

See more examples at [5.8.2 Customizing configuration metadata with a BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors) and [Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer Example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/)

Comment: yes,, for now I am using properties file. The above does work. I want to remove properties file from web app and add them in server context.xml like we do to datasource